# <a> Link around svg behaves strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

In my Website I have svg icons, i used this script:
https://github.com/tiagoporto/jquery-svg-to-inline

That works fine.

So i wrapped my icon with a  Tag:

```
 <a href="https://open.spotify.com/" target="_blank" class="svg-link"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/svg/play-white.svg"  class="svg"></a>
```

But this produces this output:

[image]

This is a shot of the firebug highlighted `<svg></svg>`

[image]

The orange part goes over the gray. I set the gray to height 60px. The svg is also 60px. There is no padding or margin on the items.

I mean I could do overflow:hidden on the gray div. But I wondered if theres a more elegant way, that the  link is only at the size of the svg - and not taller.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: try displaying your `a` tag with `display: inline-block` or `display: block`

Comment: Without further CSS rules it's just guessing: Either some wrong `float`ing or a not appropriate `display` property.

Comment: Can you please post result HTML and css applied to it?

Comment: What 3Dos wrote worked for me! Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is my working example:

```
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 svg-link-wrapper">
     <a href="#musik" class="svg-link"><img src="icon.svg"  class="svg"></a>
  </div>

.svg-link {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
}

.svg-link-wrapper {
    text-align: right;
    height: 60px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

And I just found out there would me a much better solution!
if you give the  tag a Background-Image as SVG, set height and width and ready!

```
a .svg-link { 
                background-image: url(./svg/musik.svg);
                height: 45px;
                width: 45px;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in the z-index tag.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp